# Angular is not creating new project

Tags: angular

I'm unable to create Angular project successfully.

```
F:\Demos>npm init
F:\Demos>npm install @angular/cli
```

Above two commands worked well. Then, executed the below command:

`F:\Demos>ng new my-template-driven-forms`

When executed the above command, getting below error:

```
F:\Demos>ng new my-template-driven-forms
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My npm version is: `6.14.11`, and my node version is: `v14.16.0`

Can anyone please tell me where I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Try `npx -p @angular/cli ng new ...`

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, thank you very much. It's working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run these commands:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

you can then check ng version by :

```
ng version
```

> check for error(if any) during installation

Answer (score 0):

Just open a new terminal and everything should work fine.